# concat multiple mp4 files with an effect

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a folder that contains n video files of mp4 format: 00001.mp4, 00002.mp4, etc...

They are all the same resolution, fps, and dimensions.

What I need is a way to concat them together into one large mp4 file, but to have a specific effect between every two subsequent videos.

For example a flash fade.
Here are some examples: https://biteable.com/blog/video-transitions-effects-examples/

I have access to ffmpeg and looking for some sample commands.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial here will provide you with a starting point: [link](https://www.bogotobogo.com/FFMpeg/ffmpeg_fade_in_fade_out_transitions_effects_filters_slideshow_concat.php)

What you will need to do is use:

```
ffmpeg -i slide.mp4 -y -vf fade=in:0:30 slide_fade_in.mp4
```

and:

```
ffmpeg -i slide_fade_in.mp4 -y -vf fade=out:120:30 slide_fade_in_out.mp4
```

Then combine the files with the effects. In the tutorial, they have setup the script for the combinations.

Comment: I have many files. Does that mean that I have to repeat the process for every two files in the chain?

Comment: @Nir yes, you can also use a function to do this. I posted a link to a tutorial that does this.

Comment: @Nir no problem. I am glad that I could help. If this answer was helpful please consider marking it as the answer to your question.